# How TO - Add Active Class to Current Element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a jsp page for the sidebar that I'd like to add an action class to when someone clicks on it. I'm taking the instructions of w3schools.com. link = https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp
but I'm not sure how to alter it to match my code I'm as I'm a javascript newbie. Any suggestions?

```
<body>
<div class="col-md-3" id="DIV">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="${webHome}/home">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="${webHome}/task">Task List</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" >
            <a href="${webHome}/app?domainId=${userSession.domainId}">Applications</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
    var header = document.getElementById("DIV");
    var btns = header.getElementsByTagName("presentation");
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
            current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            this.className += " active";
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: There is no element `<presentation>` in your markup, and in HTML in general. So `getElementsByTagName("presentation")` cannot find anything.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure about it. I was simply experimenting

Comment: The ```li``` tags need to have the class ```"presentation".```

Comment: Please do not edit answers into your question. This renders the answers useless.

Comment: That makes total sense , sorry about that

Comment: Also, the active isn't lasting, after clicking it stays for 1 second and then vanishes.

Comment: Yes, because the click loads a completely new page, and that one doesn't know anything about the previous click. But that would be a complete new question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Added id for each item like this

```
        <li role="presentation" id="navDashboard"><a href="${webHome}/home">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" id="navTaskList"><a href="${webHome}/task">Task List</a></li>
```

and added this javascript code

```
    const pathDashboard='/web/home';
    const pathTaskList='/web/task';
    const pathApplications ='/web/app';

    var path = window.location.pathname;

    if(path===pathDashboard){
        $('#navDashboard').each(function () {
                $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    }

    if(path===pathTaskList){
        $('#navTaskList').each(function () {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    }

and so on...
```

Comment: `$('#navDashboard').each` doesn't make any sense, that selector can only give you one result. Working with `id`s here instead of the `role` attribute is a much worse approach.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
var btns = header.getElementsByTagName("presentation");
```

with

```
const btns = header.querySelectorAll("li[role=presentation]");
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll